# Base/Home directory of the gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

As part of the RSpec, i need to reference a file contained in a gem I am depending on (call it gem foo).  I control gem foo, so I can make changes to it as needed.

Gem 'foo' contains a file that I need to reference with in the a rspec spec.  **Is there a reasonably stable RubyGem or Bundler API to figure out 'foo' base directory?**

Assuming 'foo' is already required in my Gemfile:
*in Gemfile:*

```
gem 'foo'
```

I want to do something like this (in something_spec.rb):

```
filename = File.expand_path('examples/xml/result.xml', Gem.gem_base_path('foo'))
```

What is gem_base_path API call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating a function in your gem to do this:

```
module Foo
  class Configuration
    def self.result_xml_path
      File.realpath("../examples/xml/result.xml")
    end
  end
end
```

You can then do the following in your spec:

```
filename = Foo::Configuration.result_xml_path
```

This is much safer since you are getting all the information from the gem. It also looks cleaner.

Comment: I like adding method to the target Gem.  Suspect File.realpath there should be `File.expand_path("../examples/xml/result.xml", __FILE__)`.  Is there a way to do this without modifying a target gem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you please clarify? File.realpath "Returns the real (absolute) pathname of pathname in the actual filesystem not containing symlinks or useless dots", so you should be able to use it without worrying about relative paths.

Comment: Looks like `File#realpath` takes 2 arguments, Without 2nd argument, it will return result relative to current working directory.  Think what you mean to do is return path relative to directory containing file being executed.

Comment: No, it's the opposite way. Without the second argument it returns the absolute path in the system. With the second path it returns a relative path based on that second argument.

Comment: But in order to return absolute path, it will interpret 1st argument, if it's relative, as starting at current working directory or at 2nd arg if it's not nil.  Still think will need to add `__FILE__` on 3rd line above.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying. It's up to you how you want to identify the file. I would definitely use a relative path there, either from __FILE__ or some other constant. That part is up to you. My point was simply that you should use a configuration class inside your gem for this information and that you should use File.realpath to pass the absolute path outside of your gem.

Answer (score 1):

This may do what you need without ant need to touch the `'foo'` gem:

```
matches = Gem::Specification.find_all_by_name 'foo'
spec = matches.first
filename = File.expand_path('examples/xml/result.xml', spec.full_gem_path)
```

I have used this code to make something similar to what you need (namely loading in my specs some factories defined in a gem used by my project)